# Test a component with Vitest using useNuxtApp with Nuxt 3

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, vitest

I want to test a component using the `useNuxtApp` composable.
This is the component(`MyComponent.vue`):

```
<template>
  <div class="flex justify-between">
    <span>{{ $fmt(12) }}</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
const { $fmt } = useNuxtApp()
</script>
```

`$fmt` is a plugin in `plugins` folder.

The problem is when I try to test `MyComponent.vue` with `vitest`, the test is not started and this error appears:

```
ReferenceError: useNuxtApp is not defined
```

I don't know how to mock the `useNuxtApp` composable

Answer (score 3):

Instead of mocking, you can use stubbing:

```
vi.stubGlobal("useNuxtApp", () => ({
  $fmt: vi.fn(),
}));
```

If you need to mock functions of `$fmt` (let's say `doSomething()`), then just extend it like this:

```
vi.stubGlobal("useNuxtApp", () => ({
  $fmt: { doSomething: vi.fn() },
}));
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to import `useNuxtApp` in your component:

```
<template>
  <div class="flex justify-between">
    <span>{{ $fmt(12) }}</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { useNuxtApp } from '#app'
const { $fmt } = useNuxtApp()
</script>
```

add the `#app` and `#head` aliases in `vitest.config.js` to import `useNuxtApp` in your test file also:

```
import path from 'path'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

export default {
  plugins: [vue()],
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: 'jsdom',
    setupFiles: './tests/unit/setup/index.ts',
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, '.'),
      '#app': path.resolve(
        __dirname,
        './node_modules/nuxt/dist/app/index.d.ts'
      ),
      '#head': path.resolve(
        __dirname,
        './node_modules/nuxt/dist/app/index.d.ts'
      ),
    },
  },
}
```

And finally you can mock `useNuxtApp` in your test file:

```
import { vi } from 'vitest'
import * as nuxt from '#app'
import { currency } from '@/plugins/utils/fmt-util'

// @ts-ignore
vi.spyOn(nuxt, 'useNuxtApp').mockImplementation(() => ({
  $fmt: { currency },
}))
```